# How to send a WhatsApp image without saving number

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

i have those two methods
the first one send an image to WhatsApp but after open WhatsApp it ask me to select a number on WhatsApp not go directly to number that sent with intent

```
private suspend fun shareImage(context: Context,bitmap: Bitmap) {
    //val context = LocalContext.current
    val fileName = "screenshot_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
    val file = File(context.externalCacheDir, fileName)

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
        outputStream.close()
    }

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", file))
    intent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("+201112076319") + "@s.whatsapp.net")
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

the second one send a message directly , actually I need to do the same process but with image file not text message

```
private suspend fun shareText(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+"201112076319"+
            "&text="+"Your Receipt"))
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Actually i need to do the same process but with image file not text message.